# Oracle Optimize Query

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm working with oracle pl/sql and i have a stored procedure with this query, and it is a bit convoluted, but it gets the job done, the thing is it takes like 35 minutes, and the sql developer Autotrace says that is doing a full scan even though the tables have their indexes.

So is there any way to improve this query?

```
select tipotrx, sum(saldo) as saldo, 
count(*) as totaltrx from (
 select  max(ids) as IDTRX, max(monto) as monto, min(saldo) as saldo, max(aq_data) as aq_data, thekey, tipotrx
 from (
       select t.SID as ids, (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(P.P1, 18, 12))) as monto,
       ((TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(P.P1, 18, 12)) * (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(t.acquirer_data, 13,2)) - 
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(P.P4, 3,2))))) as saldo,
       (TO_CHAR(t.trx_date, 'YYMMDD') || t.auth_code || t.trx_amount || (SELECT 
       functions.decrypt(t.card_number) FROM DUAL)) as thekey,
       t.acquirer_data AS aq_data,
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(t.acquirer_data, 12, 1)) as tipotrx
       from TBL_TRX t INNER JOIN TBL_POS P ON (t.SID = P.transaction) 
       WHERE (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(t.acquirer_data, 13,2)) >= TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(P.P4, 3,2))) 
       AND trunc(t.INC_DATE)  between (TO_DATE('20/06/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - 35) AND TO_DATE('20/06/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  ) t
  group by thekey,  tipotrx order by max(ids) desc) j 
group by tipotrx;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You are processing more than a month of data. I assume this is for a nightly/batch processing, not for interactive users. What's the current execution time? What's your target execution time?

Comment: `order by max(ids) desc` has no effect in the query. You should remove it.

Comment: `SELECT functions.decrypt(t.card_number) FROM DUAL` can be replaced with just `functions.decrypt(t.card_number)`

Comment: @TheImpaler it's for users sadly, and yes it's searching for the last 35 days, the client told me they handle about 90.000 records a day, so in that month they get more than 3 millions, i'll remove the order by max(ids)

Comment: @Tejash i'll try mate

Comment: please show the explain plan output

Comment: @Tejash the `select from dual` isn't logically necessary, but it might be getting some scalar subquery caching, especially if `functions.decrypt` isn't declared as `deterministic` and `pragma udf`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to `trunc(t.inc_date)` to check whether it falls between two date literals. Just leave it as `t.inc_date` and set the `between` clause to cover the expected range of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
trunc(t.INC_DATE) between (TO_DATE('20/06/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - 35)
                       AND TO_DATE('20/06/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

To this:

```
t.INC_DATE between (TO_DATE('20/06/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - 35)
                AND TO_DATE('21/06/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

Instead of building a function-based index you can modify the predicate to be sargable (able to use an index). Instead of using `TRUNC` to subtract from the the column, add a day minus one second to upper bound literal.

The code is more confusing but should be able to take advantage of the index. However, 35 days of data may be a large amount; the date index may not be very useful and you may need to look at other predicates.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time the index has to match exactly what's in the WHERE clause to be eligible for use. An index on the acquirer_data column cannot be used when your WHERE clause says

```
 TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(t.acquirer_data, 13,2))
```

An index on the INC_DATE cannot be used when your WHERE clause says

```
 trunc(t.INC_DATE)
```

You manipulate every column in the WHERE clause and that alone can potentially prevent the use of any normal index.

If however you create [function-based](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/indexes.html#GUID-44AD4D28-A056-4977-B2F7-AC1BC50EDC87) indexes, you can make some new indexes that match what's in your WHERE clause. That way at least there's a chance that the DB will use an index instead of doing full table scans.

```
--example function based index.
 CREATE INDEX TRUNC_INC_DATE ON TBL_TRX (trunc(t.INC_DATE));
```

Of course, new indexes take up more space and add overhead of their own. Keep using that autotrace to see if it's worth it.

Also, updating table statistics probably wont hurt either.

Comment: i'm gonna try the index with the trunc(INC_DATE), well, the thing is the acquirer_data has a lot of necessary information, so it's not optional to substring it.

Comment: There's no limit on how many function-based indexes you can add to a column. If you still need a normal index on acquirer_data for other queries that use the full value that's fine. You can still add a function-based index on "TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(t.acquirer_data, 13,2))" and keep all existing indexes.

Comment: Something else just occurred to me, do you need to truncate the INC_DATE?